# How would I add an artificial termination date to the termination date column based on two different dates for the same patient id

Tags: oracle, date, max, case, min

I need to figure out a query that will compare two EFFECTIVE dates for a given patient number with different HMOs and determine which is the later date of the two and then populate a TERMINATION date field for only the older of the two effective dates with the last day of the previous month of the newer effective date of the two. This needs to be done across multiple patient, HMO, effective date combinations in a table.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

The output is this:

```
HMO PATIENT EFFECTIVE   TERMINATION
16  221135  01-APR-18   
18  221135  01-OCT-17   
12  251181  01-SEP-16   
16  251181  01-MAR-15   
12  271126  01-MAR-15   
16  271126  01-DEC-16   
12  291141  01-DEC-16   
16  291141  01-FEB-19   
12  391134  09-MAY-13   
16  391134  01-APR-18
```

What I am trying to do via a query or queries is this:
HMO PATIENT EFFECTIVE   TERMINATION

```
16  221235  01-APR-18   
18  221235  01-OCT-17   3/31/2018

12  251381  01-SEP-16   
16  251381  01-MAR-15   8/31/2016

12  2711126 01-MAR-15   11/30/2016
16  2711126 01-DEC-16   

12  292241  01-DEC-16   1/31/2019
16  292241  01-FEB-19   

12  391534  09-MAY-13   31-MAR-19
16  391534  01-APR-18
```

I've tried using a case statement but it is unsurprisingly creating four rows per patient, hmo combo and populating two of the rows with dates and leaving two blank:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
S.HMO
,S.PATIENT
,S.EFFECTIVE
,CASE WHEN S.EFFECTIVE > E.EFFECTIVE THEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(S.EFFECTIVE, -1))
WHEN S.EFFECTIVE < E.EFFECTIVE THEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(E.EFFECTIVE, -1))
ELSE NULL END AS TERMINATION
FROM tablename S INNER JOIN tablename E ON S.PATIENT=E.PATIENT
WHERE S.PATIENT =221135
```

Any ideas or advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * from tablename order by patient, effective;

       HMO    PATIENT EFFECTIVE  TERMINATIO
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        18     221135 10/01/2017
        16     221135 04/01/2018
        16     251181 03/01/2015
        12     251181 09/01/2016
        12     271126 03/01/2015
        16     271126 12/01/2016

6 rows selected.
```

such a MERGE might do:

```
SQL> merge into tablename a
  2    using (select patient, max(effective) max_effective,
  3                           min(effective) min_effective
  4           from tablename
  5           group by patient
  6          ) x
  7    on (a.patient = x.patient)
  8  when matched then update set
  9    a.termination = x.max_effective - 1
 10    where a.effective = x.min_effective;

3 rows merged.
```

Result is then

```
SQL> select * from tablename order by patient, effective;

       HMO    PATIENT EFFECTIVE  TERMINATIO
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        18     221135 10/01/2017 03/31/2018
        16     221135 04/01/2018
        16     251181 03/01/2015 08/31/2016
        12     251181 09/01/2016
        12     271126 03/01/2015 11/30/2016
        16     271126 12/01/2016

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. It beats all the CTEs I was going to use.